# ASP.NET MVC - Replace label with validation error message?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I'd like to highlight field names instead of showing a separate error message when there is a validation error.

Is there any convenient way of doing this other than checking the ModelState Errors collection and wrapping each `.LabelFor()` in an `if`?

Also, I'd like to format labels as either bold, or add an asterisk if the model metadata has a `[Required]` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need use a custom Object.ascx file by creating either /Shared/DisplayTemplates/Object.ascx or  /Shared/EditorTemplates/Object.ascx

I can't answer any better than this guide at Brad Wilson's blog: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html